# Algorithm to distribute a discrete number by given percentages while maintaining a minimum of 1

Tags: algorithm

I need to distribute a given number of days py a given list of percentages.
The problem I'm facing is that every group must at least get 1 day (as long as n > Sum(g))

```
n = number of Days to distribute
g_i = number of days for the group with the name i
p_i = wanted percentage for the group with the name i
Sum(g) = number of groups;
```

So my first step is to iterate all the groups and give them 1 day as long as there are enough days.
E.g.:

```
foreach(group)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        g_i = 1;
        n = n - 1;
    }
}
```

Now I dont know what to do next.
I have to distribute the remaining days based on the given percentage but the percantage is based on the original number of days and not on the remaining number of days.
So somehow I have to recalculate the percentages so they are based on the remaining number of days and not on the original number of days.

EDIT:
I came up with the following pseudo code:

```
pd = 1 / n (the percentage for one day)

if(sum(g) == 1)
{
    g_i = n;
}
else if(sum(g) < n)
{
    give every group one day as long as there are days left, starting with the group with the highest percentage
}
else
{
    while(n > 0)
    {
        l = group with lest percentage greater than zero;
        g_l = g_l + 1;
        p_l = p_l - pd;
        n = n - 1;
    }
}
```

So basically im getting the group with the least percentage, assign it a day and update the percentage.

Is someone has a better answer, im up for improving this algorith :)

Comment: Assign by percentages by the obvious way then afterwards go through anything that has less than 1 day and give it one day. Take these extra days from the people with the most days.

Answer (score 0):

I would assign them randomly until the remaining number of days equals the number of empty groups.

```
emptyGroups = Sum(g);

// Random assignment
while (n > emptyGroups) {
    i = chooseAGroup();
    if (g_i == 0) emptyGroups--;
    g_i++;
}

// Assign the remaining days to empty groups
foreach(group) {
  if n > 0 && g_i == 0) {
    g_i = 1;
    n--;
  }
}
```